# RRQ for a file to TFTP server

Tags: java, file, network-programming, nio, tftp

On sending RRQ for a file in TFTP Server, I am receiving this error message in server

```
Connection received from 127.0.0.1 on port 58412 [20/05 09:56:28.783]
Unexpected request 0 from peer [20/05 09:56:28.783]
Returning EBADOP to Peer [20/05 09:56:28.783]
```

On executing the below code, I have received this error

```
DatagramChannel client=DatagramChannel.open();
SocketAddress address = new java.net.InetSocketAddress(host,69);
client.connect(address);
client.configureBlocking(false);
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(512);
buffer.put((byte)0);
buffer.put((byte)1);
buffer.put("test.rtf".getBytes());
buffer.put((byte)0);
buffer.put("octet".getBytes());
buffer.put((byte)0);
client.send(buffer, address);
```

Am stuck with this stage. Any help is highly appreciated

I also tried running code available in http://www.javased.com/?source_dir=PSP-NetParty/src/pspnetparty/lib/socket/AsyncUdpClient.java. This too leads to same error while sending RRQ for a file